# How can I block WGET to specfic domain from server?

Tags: firewall, wget

I have many js nodes running and the scripts cannot be stopped or changed. (Including the code for the scripts)

The script makes requests to a domain, say, example.com. It is spamming this domain too much and I want to block outgoing attempts at loading it from the node server.

I've tried SSHing into the node server and updating the hosts file at `/etc/hosts` with:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com www.example.com
```

But that hasn't stopped the requests going out. Is there a way I can do this with a firewall or another method?

Thank you

Server information from `cat /etc/*-release`:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate OS on the servers making the requests.  A firewall can probably be used to block application-specific requests, but the specifics are complicated, depending on firewall make, model, version.  Better to do it locally on the nodes like you tried.  Also, "scripts cannot be stopped or changed" makes me think that they might not respect changes to the hosts file until the process is started again.  On desktop Windows, Chrome won't respect hosts file changes immediately.

Comment: Thank you, I have added server information. It's an Ubuntu server 16.04. I was under the assumption that firewalls can only block incoming requests? I don't know much about it though.

Comment: If you need to throttle the script the best approach would be to change the script. Making the block specific to just WGET is probably not going to work. Having a general block using the hosts file or using a firewall will probably work. You could setup an outgoing iptables rule to block connections to the destination host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is using an iptables rule. Let's assume that example.com resolves to 10.10.10.10, and I only want to block communication on port 443.  I'd use a command on the client like

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

To remove the rule -

```
iptables -D OUTPUT -d 10.10.10.10 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

Comment: It would be fiddly, but you could even limit the frequency of connection attempts using the connlimit module for iptables (Google iptables connlimit for various options for it)